# AWS S3 local server for integration testing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

I have some code that uploads and downloads files using AWS S3 (using the Java AWS SDK). I want to be able to write some tests for it, I was wondering if anyone has any good options. Ideally I would like a light-weight S3 server that runs locally that can be started fast and requires no system configuration (the tests need to be run by Jenkins).

Some options I have looked at so far:

1. [**FakeS3**](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) - Almost exactly what I'm looking for, however, when using the Java AWS SDK, you must edit your /etc/hosts file and restart networking, not something I can do in Jenkins. Also when trying it out there seems to be a bug with the creation date field being formatted wrong which makes my client throw an exception, which doesn't inspire me with much confidence in the project.
2. **Ceph** - Implements S3 API but takes several minutes to install

Comment: There is also Swift3, but it would be even more complex to set up. Perhaps having a server set up outside jenkins, instead of setting up in the test suite?

Comment: Yeah that's another option, didn't think of that. It's much nicer to have completely self contained tests though, you don't want to have to VPN into a network with the S3 server set up just to run your tests.

Comment: For that i belive setting the hosts file in the jenkins machine and running on FakeS3, or just mocking the S3 client interface, could be a better solution...

Comment: It's quite a big interface to mock, and I would rather avoid using mocks if at all possible, as you end up tying your tests to the implementation.

Comment: May be s3ninja.net ?

Answer (score 23):

You can try [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), which is an open source local AWS cloud stack made for testing. It provides implementations of several of AWS services, including S3.

It looks like a very popular open source project on GitHub.

Comment: Do you know if you can connect to a local S3 running from localstack through a SFTP client? I am not finding anything in the documentation. Maybe is not possible.

Answer (score 18):

You can try installing [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio) server on your laptop/system, its open source & single static binary. Server is S3 compatible. Then you can try [minio-java client library](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) for all operations, following is basic [operations example](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/tree/master/examples).

Installing minio server [GNU/Linux]

```
$ wget https://dl.minio.io/server/minio/release/linux-amd64/minio
$ chmod 755 minio
$ ./minio --help
```

Hope it helps
Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Comment: Minio does not support tags unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

Late answer, will be useful mostly for Docker users. There's a great S3 compatible storage software called [Riak CS](https://github.com/basho/riak_cs) and there's [docker-riak-cs](https://github.com/ianbytchek/docker-riak-cs) image that allows to quickly launch the server.

I've been using it for nearly 2 years for local development and integration testing with great success. It has some limitations, but nothing major that comes in the way, see api / compatibility [documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/cs/2.1.1/references/apis/storage/s3/).

If you need Docker-less solution, you can set it up locally for each build, all setup and configuration scripts are available in [docker-riak-cs](https://github.com/ianbytchek/docker-riak-cs) repository.

Comment: can you please tell how to connect to riak-cs local server in place of s3

Comment: I want my existing code base to run against riak-cs in place of s3

Comment: I looked at docker-riak-cs but it didn't look like I could automatically configure it with keys for unsupervised integration tests. How did you do it?

Comment: Riak CS doesn't allow to specify custom credentials for security reasons. Docker image provides this for cases when you already have data and want to mount it, this is mentioned in [configuration](https://github.com/ianbytchek/docker-riak-cs#configuration). After container starts you can get credentials from logs, see how it's done in [test.sh](https://github.com/ianbytchek/docker-riak-cs/blob/d3324f8582831269a5088ee63d2d34d6787b19f3/build/ci/script/test.sh#L30-L35).

Comment: The [repo seems to be no longer maintained](https://github.com/ianbytchek/docker-riak-cs/issues/13#issuecomment-419885808) and startup times are atrocious (90s+ on decent hardware!).

Answer (score 6):

[Minio](https://docs.min.io/) offers (in my opinion) the best set of features, flexibility and ease of use.
It is available as a docker container or binary for major OSes.

To start with [minio](https://min.io/), it is as easy as:

- Download
- Start the binary `minio server /data`
- Use it

It works flawlessly with s3cmd and it has nice documentation for popular programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

I started a S3 Server API project for Ladon, it contains a simple File System Repository. Its a Java Project and contains a Spring Boot Starter for simple testing. Not all S3 API features are supported yet but I will add them on request. Its on Github: [Ladon S3 Server](https://github.com/mindmill/ladon-s3-server)

Answer (score 3):

[findify/s3mock](https://github.com/findify/s3mock) - an in-process, Java S3 server aimed at testing. Didn't test it - just stumbled upon it. Needs no docker, which might be an advantage. HTH! :)

Comment: great tip, this worked great for me. similar to using wiremock in tests, if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

ive tried both minio and localstack, and the problem with localstack is that the storage in the s3 bucket is not persistence. I think only if you have the pro version it will support percistency. minio was very easy to use, and it is persistent for free.

Answer (score -7):

I created different buckets to use for the different use cases. For example: my-dev-bucket and my-prod-bucket. I don't know if this meets your use criteria but you might want to consider it. The side benefit is it makes your pre production and production code follow the exact same flows.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. OP is asking for a local solution so he doesn't have to spend $$$ when running his Integration tests.....