# How can i use S3Mock to test downloading a file locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have realised a code that download files with s3 bucket using spring boot.
I want know to perform some tests for methods but i don't know how to use S3Mock to do that can everyone help me in that ?
I want a test method to get xml files from an s3 bucket any ideas for the code please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991694/aws-s3-local-server-for-integration-testing

Comment: @psyco i want the code for the test because i find a lot of problems ...