# What is the best approach in nodejs to switch between the local filesystem and Amazon S3 filesystem?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, fs

I'm looking for the best way to switch between using the local filesystem and the Amazon S3 filesystem.

I think ideally I would like a wrapper to both filesystems that I can code against. A configuration change would tell the wrapper which filesystem to use. This is useful to me because a developer can use their local filesystem, but our hosted environments can use Amazon S3 by just changing a configuration option.

Are there any existing wrappers that do this? Should I write my own wrapper?
Is there another approach I am not aware of that would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea to build a wrapper that can use either the local file system or S3. I'm not aware of anything existing that would provide that for you, but would certainly be interested to hear if you find anything.

An alternative would be to use some sort of S3 file system mount, so that your application can always use standard file system I/O but the data might be written to S3 if your system has that location configured as an S3 mount. I don't recommend this approach because I've never heard of an S3 mounting solution that didn't have issues.

Another alternative is to only design your application to use S3, and then use some sort of S3 compatible local object storage in your development environment. There are several answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210162/is-there-a-server-that-provides-an-amazon-s3-style-api-locally) that could provide an S3 compatible service during development.

Comment: I like your suggestion of desiging the app to us S3 and using an S3 compatible local object store for development. In the link you posted I found out about [S3 Ninja](http://s3ninja.net/) that seems like it might be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a project named [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) that offers a subset of POSIX file system function on top of S3. There's no native Amazon-provided way to do this.

However, you should think long and hard about whether or not this is a sensible option. S3 is an object store, not a regular file system, and it has quite different performance and latency characteristics.

If you're looking for high iops, NAS-style storage then Amazon EFS (in preview) would be more appropriate. Or roll your own [NFS/CIFS solution](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/nfs-and-cifs-options-for-aws-stg401-aws-reinvent-2013) using EBS volumes or [SoftNAS](https://www.softnas.com/wp/nas-storage/softnas-cloud-aws-nfs-cifs/) or [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/).

Comment: s3fs looks interesting! Yes, I think you're right that I need to really figure out if this is the correct route for my project. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a service called [JuiceFS](https://juicefs.com/docs/en/intro.html) that can do what you want.

According to their documentation:

> JuiceFS is a POSIX-compatible shared filesystem specifically designed
> to work in the cloud.
>
> It is designed to run in the cloud so you can utilize the cheap price
> of object storage service to store your data economically.
>
> It is a
> POSIX-compatible filesystem so you can access your data seamlessly as
> accessing local files.
>
> It is a shared filesystem so you can share your
> files across multiple machines.

`s3` is one of the backends supported, you can even configure it to replicate files to a different object storage system on another cloud.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know about! I was specifically asking about node.js wrappers, but I do understand how this is a possible solution. I'm not sure why you removed the node.js tag. I have re-added it so that people in the node.js community can find this post more easily.